# Unable to set action for mobile and web platform

Tags: php, push-notification, urbanairship.com

We are using Airship API to send push notification on mobile and web platforms and for deep linking we are using action like

```
"notification": {
    "actions": {
        "open": {
            "type": "deep_link",
            "content": "https://www.urbanairship.com/settings",
        }
    }
}
```

and web action is:

```
"notification": {
    "actions": {
        "open": {
            "type": "url",
            "content": "http://www.urbanairship.com"
        }
    },
}
```

Above parameters working well as individually but we want to use both parameters together like in attached screen shot "screenshot.png". We didn't find any solution on documentation that show how to use deep linking and web action together same as attached screen shot. So could you suggest us how to merge these parameters so that we can use deep linking action for mobile devices and web action for websites together?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this and may be useful for someone.

Here's an example payload:

```
{
    "audience": "all",
    "device_types": ["ios", "android", "web"],
    "notification": {
        "alert": "Opening this message will open a defined deep link.",
        "actions": {
            "open": {
                "type": "deep_link",
                "content": "prefs",  // for mobile platform
                "fallback_url": "https://airship.com" // for web platform
            }
        }
    }
}
```